# A bipartite graph with the degree sequence {5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Does there exist a simple bipartite graph with the degree sequence {5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9}? I believe the answer is no but cannot prove this. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there exists such graph $G(U,V,E)$ with 14 vertices with $|V|\geq |U|$. Since one vertex has degree 9, the vertex set not containing this vertex must have at least 9 vertices, i.e., $|V|\geq 9$ and $|U|\leq 5$. All eight vertices of degree 8 must also be in $U$ because otherwise their degrees should be at most 5. But now we have a contradiction: $U$ now has at least 9 vertices including 8 vertices of degree 8 and one vertex of degree 9.

Comment: Thanks but I do not get the part " because otherwise their degrees should be at most 5". Can you explain this if possible.

Comment: @user81883: What I meant was if the vertices of degree 8 were in $V$, then each of them can be connected to at most 5 vertices in $U$ as we have established $|U|\leq 5$.